# Is it possible to sync my dictionary like I do my bookmarks and preferences?

Tags: sync, cloud, dictionary, persistent

Modern browsers allow me to keep important things like passwords, bookmarks, etc. synced up in 'The Cloud'. I mainly use Firefox and Chrome.

However, I'm unaware of a way to sync the changes I've made to the browser's dictionary. Every new computer I use I need to teach my style of spelling.

Are there any plugins, add-ons, or other ways of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1):

sorry but did you mean the one browsers use to correct our typing? nor known to such sync service that browser provides then.

but if it is file-based, some symbolic link and service like `dropbox` may help.

#actually I use dropbox to synchronize my firefox profile across 3 computers. (they won't be running at the same time, so I don't have to face the conflict problem. )

Comment: Yes, I mean the dictionary in the browser. I'll clarify my question to reflect this. BTW, the Dropbox solution is a pretty good idea. I would prefer to have an extension mind you.

Answer (score 1):

**To do it manually:**
In *Chrome* the user added spellings are stored at `C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and look for `Custom Dictionary.txt`. (It will only be present if you have a custom spelling entry)

Then sync it with your cloud service using [Symbolic Links](http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder).

Answer (score 0):

Chromium and Google Chrome added the feature to version 26. The feature is available in Linux, Windows and Chrome OS but not Mac OS yet:

- [New Google Chrome release improves in-browser spell chekcer](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/03/new-google-chrome-release-improves-in-browser-spell-chekcer/) @ ArsTechnica
- [Oodles of improvements to Chrome’s spell checking](http://chrome.blogspot.fr/2013/03/oodles-of-improvements-to-chromes-spell.html) @ Chrome Blog